# Only part of background image shows within asp panel

Tags: css, asp.net, background-image, updatepanel, panel

I have created an .aspx page. The page contains one panel and within the panel, two update panels (right panel, left panel). In side the left update panel are two `div` tags, one representing the top half of the left update panel and the other `div` representing the bottom of the left update panel. It is the same with the right update panel. The bottom `div` in the left update panel has a Gridview.

I want to add a single (no-repeat) background image to the entire panel, so that the background image covers the whole of the panel area. When I add a background image to the panel, it only covers the top-left update panel and the top-right update panel, thereby leaving the bottom part of both update panels bare.

I have also used `user controls` to represent the Header, Left Navigation panel and the Right sliding panel. But I don't want the background image to be applied to the header or the two side panels, just the center panel.

I tried giving `BackgroundImageURL` to the panel, as well as, using `CssClass` attribute to link to a css class including the background image.

Here's my code (.aspx) :

```
<body>
    <Header:main runat="server" ID="header"></Header:main>
    <Leftpnl:left runat="server" ID="pnlLeft"></Leftpnl:left>
    <RightPnl:right runat="server" ID="pnlRight"></RightPnl:right>

    <div class="Title">
        <h2>Tickets</h2>

        <hr class="Sub_Title_HR" />
    </div>

    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_New_First" runat="server">
            <div class="Sub_Heading">
                <asp:Label ID="Sub_1" runat="server" Text="Plan Your Trip"></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <asp:Panel ID="Panel_1" runat="server" CssClass="Pnl_BG">
                <div class="New_Left">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="Cell_Size">
                                        <asp:Label ID="New_Dep_Title" runat="server" Text="Departure"></asp:Label>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="Cell_Size">
                                        <asp:Label ID="New_Arr_Title" runat="server" Text="Arrival"></asp:Label>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="Cell_Size">
                                        <asp:Label ID="New_Date_Title" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="Cell_Size">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="New_Dep_DDL" CssClass="DDL" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ListItem>IND</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>KUL</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="Cell_Size">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="New_Arr_DDL" CssClass="DDL" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ListItem>CMB</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>KUL</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="New_Date1" Skin="Default" runat="server" DateInput-DateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <asp:Button ID="New_Search" runat="server" Text="Search" />
                                   </td>
                                </tr>
                                <br /><br />
                            </table>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <table id="UL_Outbound_Tab">
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="New_Outbound_Head">Outbound : <asp:Label ID="Dep_Airport" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> To <asp:Label ID="Arr_Airport" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <asp:GridView ID="New_Outbound_Grid" runat="server">
                                </asp:GridView>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="New_Add" runat="server" Text="Add" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>

                <div class="New_Right">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="New_My_Trip_Head" runat="server" Text="My Trip"></asp:Label>

                            <table id="New_My_Trip_Tab">
                                <asp:GridView ID="My_Trip_Grid" runat="server">
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </table>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="New_Tick_Val_Head" runat="server" Text="Ticket Validity Period"></asp:Label>

                            <table id="New_Tick_Val_Tab">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Val_From" runat="server" Text="Valid From : "></asp:Label>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="Val_From_Date" Skin="Default" runat="server" DateInput-DateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" style="margin-left: 0px"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                    </td>

                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Val_To" runat="server" Text="Valid To : "></asp:Label>
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="Val_To_Date" Skin="Default" runat="server" DateInput-DateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" style="margin-left: 0px"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <caption>
                                    <tr style="margin-top: 5%">
                                        <td style="width: 35%">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Val_Com" runat="server" Text="User Comments : "></asp:Label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Val_Com_Txt" runat="server" Rows="5" TextMode="MultiLine" style="width: 150%; resize: none" placeholder="Text Here"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </caption>
                            </table>

                            <asp:ImageButton class="next1 Left_Right_Controls" runat="server" OnClientClick="next1()" ImageUrl="~/Images/Buttons/page_right_arrow.png" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </asp:panel>    

            <div id="step_init" class="Steps">
                <img src="Images/Steps/1.png" alt="" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here's my CSS :

```
.Pnl_BG {
    background-image: url(../Images/travelling.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Please help...

Comment: what is your code???

Comment: @Andrew Just added it...